# Hyperbolic solutions to 2 coupled ODE's

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand the authors' solution to the following relativity problem:

> A particle is accelerating along the $x^1$-axis. The components of the four acceleration satisfy (ignoring the $x^2$ and $x^3$ directions)
> $$ca^0=Au^1, \qquad ca^1=Au^0$$
> where $A$ is a constant. Suppose that the particle is at rest when $\tau = 0$. Determine $u^0(\tau)$ and $u^1(\tau)$. Find $x^0(\tau)$ and $x^1(\tau)$ assuming that $x^0 = x^1 = 0$ when $\tau = 0$. Sketch the worldline of the particle on a space-time diagram.

The beginning of the solution to this question is

> Write the equations as $a^0=\alpha u^1$, $a^1=\alpha u^0$, where $\alpha=A/c$. This yields a system of first-order ODEs for $u_0$ and $u_1$:
> $$\frac{du^0}{d \tau}=\alpha u^1,\quad \frac{du^1}{d \tau}=\alpha u^0\tag{1}$$
> General solution $$\color{red}{u^0=C\cosh(\alpha \tau)+D\sinh(\alpha \tau),\,\,\,u^1=C\sinh(\alpha \tau)+D\cosh(\alpha \tau)}$$
> where $C$ and $D$ are arbitrary constants.
> .
> .
> .
> .

I could keep writing the rest of the solution, but there is no point as I can't understand how the author was able to deduce that the solutions (marked in red) take that form.

Taking the first ODE,
$$\frac{du^0}{d \tau}=\alpha u^1$$

and separating the variables, such that $du^0=\alpha u^1 d\tau$, since $u^0$ and $u^1$ are functions of proper time, $\tau$. I would then have to integrate by parts, twice,

$$\begin{align}u^0=\int du^0 = \alpha\int  u^1 d\tau &=\alpha u^1 \tau - \alpha\int\tau \frac{du^1}{d\tau}d\tau\\&=\alpha u^1 \tau - \alpha\left(\tau u^1-\int u^1 d\tau\right)\\&=\alpha \int u^1 d\tau\end{align}$$

This is exactly where I started, so integrating by parts does not work in this scenario. Normally in these situations I would use a trial solution like $u^0=\exp(m \tau)$ where $m$ is a constant. But the part that confuses me here is that there is more than one variable to solve for ($u^0(\tau)$ and $u^1(\tau)$).

So in short, how did the author deduce that the general solution would take the form (marked red) in the above quote?

Comment: While Ishans answer below gives the result, it assumes some information about the differentiability of $u^{0}, u^{1}$ that is not given in the problem. You should solve it as a [matrix ODE problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation), which is essentially diagonalising the equation set to decouple the two problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard system of two first-order linear ODEs, which can easily be solved by converting this into a single second-order linear ODE as
\begin{equation}
\frac{\text{d}^2 u^0}{\text{d}\tau^2} = \alpha \frac{\text{d} u^1}{\text{d}\tau} = \alpha^2 u^0
\end{equation}

This can easily be solved to get the equation in red.